# No user groups when luching from krunner (systemd --user)

Tags: linux, kde, systemd, kde-plasma-workspace

I've noticed that when running `konsole` via that `krunner`, `id` do not return any additional groups. When `konsole` is launched from the activator bar menu, `id` return proper groups.

Looks for me like something is messed up with the sessions handling, as in both cases `env` also gives very difference results. It is quite fresh Arch Linux installation and I think I messed something up with some config, which I most likely hadn't touched yet.

The processes tree looks as on the screenshot:

[image: process tree]

the one which is child of `plasmashell` is fine, the `systemd` one is not

So as stated bellow in the answer, processes ran through the `krunner` are spawned using user space `systemd`, but the question is **why additional user groups are not set for them?**. Is there some config option I forgot to set or what?

What is starting the user-space systemd, maybe here is problem?

Content of `/etc/systemd/user.conf` is entirely commented out

Comment: I reported this as an issue on the systemd https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/21854

Answer (score 1):

Groups are inherited. If you changed your groups, the existing session processes will continue to fork new processes with the old groups. If you changed your groups *and logged out,* it might still be that some KDE components (e.g. possibly `kded` or `dbus-daemon`) did not immediately shut down and were actually re-used for the subsequent login, so if apps are being started indirectly, through those components, they'll continue inheriting the old groups.

In particular, KDE and GNOME might launch applications through the per-user `systemd --user` service manager – which runs in background (unassociated with any specific session) for as long as you have *any* sessions, and exits ~10 seconds after all your sessions have been closed. The same applies to `dbus-daemon` as long as it is managed by systemd.

Log out, then wait ~30 seconds before logging in again. Alternatively, log in to console (tty) and run `ps axf` to check what leftover processes you might have running. (If the systemd manager has too many leftover KDE processes running, `systemctl --user exit` should clean it up.)

Comment: may it survive reboot?